# How to distinguish sql from scripting in google big query sql with ZetaSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with ZetaSQL (https://github.com/google/zetasql) java implementation with following dependencies:

compile group: 'com.google.zetasql', name: 'zetasql-client', version: '2020.08.1'
compile group: 'com.google.zetasql', name: 'zetasql-types', version: '2020.08.1'
compile group: 'com.google.zetasql', name: 'zetasql-jni-channel-linux', version: '2020.08.1'
compile group: 'com.google.zetasql', name: 'zetasql-jni-channel', version: '2020.08.1'

I am trying to parse bigquery sql to get referenced table and columns, but it looks like that ZetaSQL is not supporting bigquery sql scripting and insert statement.

So I am wondering what's the best way to distinguish sql from scripting?

And if there is a way to parse insert statement with ZetaSQL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have been using parsing with below method.
Assumption is that you have access to Dictionary tables, (either in form of INFORMATION_SCHEMA or dbc.tables in Teradata or v_tables/views in Netezza)

The overall thought is this way

1. First replace all the characters in the query with space except [0-9a-zA-Z._] (Note that I have taken dots and Underscore too)
   `REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING_AGG(QueryText) , r'[^a-zA-Z0-9._]', ' ') replace_query`
2. Then split the querytext based on space and get an array of all word used in the query.
   `SPLIT(replace_query,' ') words`
3. Then flatten the array and directly join with dataset.tablename from INFORMATION_SCHEMA
   `UNNEST(words)`

if you parsing BQ queries, then BQ allows following format
`projectname.dataset.tablename` and `dataset.tablename`.

So next step
Step 4) Build a case statement to check only those records which have either 1 or 2 dots
`CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(words, r'[.]'))= 1` then join with `dataset.tablename`

`CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(words, r'[.]'))= 2` then join with `project.dataset.tablename`

Whatever is joined, is your set of referenced dataset and tables

Hope these steps helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am wondering how can I distinguish sql from scripting? and if there is a way to parse insert statement?